# is there an OnActivate method for angular?

Tags: angular

I currently have an angular page which implements `ngOnInit()`.

Currently i am on /home and after clicking the home link it doesn't trigger `ngOnInit()`, is there any onActivate()?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPage(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution, but i solved it. Below are the codes i have came up with in case anybody needs it too. feel free to comment on how i can improve the code. Thanks!

```
//app-routing.module.ts
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
        title: 'Home'
    },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
}
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})


//home.component.ts

export class HomeComponent extends OnActivate implements OnInit {
    constructor(public router: Router) {
        super(router);
    }

    initialisePage(): void {
        this.getPage(1);
    }

}

//OnActivate.ts
export class OnActivate {

    navigationSubscription;

    constructor(
        public router: Router
    ) {

        this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
            if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.initialisePage();
            }
        });
    }

    initialisePage() {

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.navigationSubscription) {
            this.navigationSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it's better use some like if (this.router.url=='/Home') this.getPage(1) else this.router.navigateTo(['/Home'];

Comment: problem is, if the current route is `/home`, clicking a link with `routerLink='/home'` doesn't do anything. OnInit and the constructor is only triggered when you first visited the link.